# DomainService: .Include() on client

Tags: silverlight, entity-framework, ria, expression-trees, domainservices

is there any possibility to include sub entities in my query on the client?
I'm working on a Silverlight application using RIA Services, a DomainService and EntityFramework behind it for my database access.
In Order to get associated entities when calling the DomainService for data, I have to modify the DomainService' metadata with the [Include] attribute and use the Include() method on the DomainService.
*(e. g. ObjectContext.Parent.Include("Child"))*

However, I feel like ending up with a ton of methods for each entity in my DomainService to get all different combinations of associated data, because sometimes I'll need a *user* and the associated *role*, sometimes I only want to get the user without any associated data and so on...

According to some RIA tutorials, it is recommended to use the functionality given by Expression Trees to modify a query on the client side.
Is there any way of including on the client instead of the DomainService' get-method? 
I feel like this must be a common issue when working with DomanServices?!

During my research, I stumbled over a similar question but without any answer and another thread where someone said it is not possible. But that answer was posted around April 2009 and there have been a lot of changes in the development since then.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can query method on the server.  Let say you have this code on server:

```
public IQueryable<Employee> GetEmployeesSorted()
{
    return from Employee emp in ObjectContext.Employees
    orderby emp.Title, emp.HireDate
    select emp;
}
```

you can use like this on client

```
EmployeeContext context = new EmployeeContext();

    EntityQuery<Employee> query =
        from emp in context.GetEmployeesSortedQuery()
        where emp.SalariedFlag == true
        select emp;
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks you for your really fast answer.

I know about that, but the Include() method to join associated entities only works directly one the ObjectQuery in the DomainService.
The point is that I don't want to change the DomainService Code a lot.
The best would be, if i could just stick with the generated code and do all modify operations on the query client side.

Comment: @Christoph - the whole point of `.Include` is to eager-load the data on the server. I think what you should do is accept an array of associations to include when you call your domain service. The service can then eager load. E.g `var empsWithOrders = domainService.GetEmployees(new[] { "Orders", "Orders.Products" })`. Use an extension method in your domain service to convert to `.Include`. You can make this more type-safe with enums or complex generics (i use the latter).

Comment: Okay, since I can't include directly through my call on the client, this seems like a nice workaround to me.
Thanks for your idea.